# Can I use Neudesic Azure Storage Explorer to access Azure China?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-china

I've used Neudesic Azure Storage Explorer v4.0.0.10 to access Azure in North America but now I need to access storage in Azure China (codename Mooncake)

According to the portal, storage is up and running. However, using Storage Explorer with the correct credentials returns various errors like "an error occurred while processing this request"

Is Azure China supported by Neudesic Azure Storage Explorer?

Comment: Is Azure China different from Azure, or are you just referring to a different data center?

Comment: China is different from WW Azure (worldwide); they have different endpoints and service bus namespaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that Azure Storage Explorer has hard coded URL endpoints for storage. Which when they were all the same, that made sense.  I'm ASSUMING that storage endpoints in China are different from all the others.  Which would lead me to think that the Storage Explorer tool would need an update to handle the Chinese locations.

Comment: We're in the final stages of implementation in AzureWatch for Azure China.  Azure China has different endpoints and requires Azure Storage SDK 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

There may be some differences with Azure China relating to geographic isolation and governmental rules. I'm just guessing. No one has had any problem accessing other regions with Azure Storage Explorer across the US, Europe, and Asia.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the endpoint is different comparing with Azure global. You could modify the code if want it support Azure Mooncake.

```
<Setting name="DataConnectionString" value=
"BlobEndpoint=https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.chinacloudapi.cn/;
  QueueEndpoint=https://mystorageaccount.queue.core.chinacloudapi.cn/;
  TableEndpoint=https://mystorageaccount.table.core.chinacloudapi.cn/;
  AccountName=mystorageaccount;AccountKey=<AccountKey> " />
```

For more, refer to http://www.windowsazure.cn/zh-cn/develop/other/developerdifferences/